# Jquery cant delete cloned Div

Tags: jquery, clone

I am cloning a div with form elements inside - and this is working absolutely fine. The issue i am having is when it comes to deleting a cloned div

My jquery:

```
$(".remove").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    var entry_id = $(this).attr('id');
    if($("#clinic_locations_area > div").length > 1) {
        $("#"+entry_id).slideUp(function(){$(this).remove()});
    } else {
        alert('Not allowed to delete last location');
    }
});
```

I can delete the first div (Which is not cloned) but i can not delete a cloned element

Can anyone help? thanks

Comment: If used `clone()` then use `clone(true)` else use event delegation `$(document).on('click', '.remove', function() { ... });`

Comment: ^ should be `clone(true, true)` so it does a deep copy on the events of the child elements too, just to cover all bases.

Comment: Please see my next problem, thanks